# !dumpobj in windbg,what does Domain:Value dynamic statics NYI 002a8428:NotInit mean?

Tags: windbg, sos

When i use windbg  ***!do*** to view a address,it output:

```
0:000> !do 01ef30f4 
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Byte[], mscorlib]]
MethodTable: 0021285c
EEClass:     6313a530
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
633b70a0  4000ca6        4      System.Object[]  0 instance 01eed1b8 _items
63402df0  4000ca7        c         System.Int32  1 instance        0 _size
63402df0  4000ca8       10         System.Int32  1 instance        0 _version
633ffa60  4000ca9        8        System.Object  0 instance 00000000 _syncRoot
633b70a0  4000caa        0      System.Object[]  0   shared   static _emptyArray

     **Domain:Value dynamic statics NYI 002a8428:NotInit**
```

What's the meaning of **Domain:Value dynamic statics NYI 002a8428:NotInit**?

Answer (score 1):

For static fields, `!do` displays the static field's value in each AppDomain you have. The first value, `002a8428`, is the AppDomain address, and the second value is the static field's value in that AppDomain.